# PIC Micro computer - using timer 3 as asyn counter - pull up

Tags: pic18

I am using a PIC18(L)F1XK22.  I'm trying to use timer 3 as a synchronous counter.

The PIC is running using the internal oscillator.

```
CONFIG  FOSC    = IRC       ; Internal oscillator
```

This should turn off use of pin RA5 as an external oscillator.

T1OSCEN in T1CON is 0, TMR3CS in T3CON is 1. I have set the RA5 TRIS bit and cleared the RA5 WPU bit.

My problem is that pin RA5 (T13CLKI) looks like it has a active pull up or is being driven by something.

I have the following resistor network in front of RA5.

+5---10K------X-----24K----->RA5

Point X is driven by a hall effect sensor.  When X is 0 volts, RA5 is 2.2 volts.  Decreasing the 24K resistor to 10K reduces X to 1.1 volts.  I have to reduce the resistor to about 4K before the counter works.

Here is the code I used to set up the timer...

```
#define TM3CK_TRIS    TRISA,TRISA5,A  
#define TM3CK_WPU     WPUA,WPUA5,A

        BCF         PIE2,TMR3IE,A       ; Disable Timer3 interrupt

        BSF         TM3CK_TRIS          ; set RA5 (T13CKI) as input

        BCF         TM3CK_WPU           ; disable weak pull up on RA5
                                        ;  pull up and isolation resistor are external

        CLRF        TMR3H,A             ; clear Timer 3
        CLRF        TMR3L,A

        MOVLW       0x8F                ; 1xxx xxxx RD16    16 bit read/write
                                        ; x0xx xxxx         unused bit
                                        ; xx00 xxxx T3CKPS  1:1 prescale
                                        ; xxxx 1xxx T3CCP1  something to do with comparators 
                                        ; xxxx x1xx T3SYNC  Do not sychronize with external clock
                                        ; xxxx xx1x TMR3CS  external clock from RA5 (T13CKI)
                                        ; xxxx xxx1 TMR3ON  enable timer
        MOVWF       T3CON,A

        BCF         TM3CK_WPU       
        BSF         INTCON2,RABPU,A     ; disable all pull ups
```

The last two lines were added in a vain attempt to turn off all pull ups after the timer was started.

Any help or idea much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a damaged PIC chip, swapped in a spare and the problem went away.